# How to concatanate text into a bigger field?

Tags: long-text-area, text

I need to keep some kind of a log system.
In one text field the users will enter text, and once saved, the data will be concatanted to a bigger text field with [usercreate] and the entrytextfield will be cleared, ready for the next entry.

I can create a simple flow to accomplish that, but I think there's already a standard field for that, just can't find it.

Can anyone remind me what's the field's name ?

Comment: I'm not sure there's such a field. Maybe you're thinking of field history?

Comment: definitely not field history :-P

Comment: There's no standard field for that.  It's a bad design because eventually it would run out of space plus it's impossible to run useful reports.